# Is there anything special about input boxes that would cause them to not respond to a jQuery click event?

Tags: jquery

I have jquery code that responds to an on click event when I use the all selector. I want to change it so that it responds only when a user clicks a particular ID. But when I change the code to respond to a particular ID instead of to all IDs, it no longer works. I know I am spelling the ID correctly and [using the proper syntax](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/). The javascript console shows no errors. So I am confused about what might be going wrong.

This works:

```
 $("*").click(function() {
                 $('center').fadeOut(1000, function() {
                    });
            });
```

This does not work:

```
             $("#answerBox").click(function() {
                 $('center').fadeOut(1000, function() {
                    });
            });
```

I know that I am spelling the ID correctly:

[image]

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id='left'>
                <p  id='answerprompt'>Answer: </p>
                <input id="answerBox" type="text" name="firstname">
            </div>
```

Here is all the CSS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#recycleButton").click(function(){
                 $("#captchaText").attr('src', 'cryptographp.inc.php');
        });
        $("#submitButton").click(function(){

                $.ajax({
                    url: 'getRejection.php',
                   success: function(data) { alert(data) }
                });
                $('#captchaPanel').animate({ opacity: 1}, 200);

                $("#captchaText").attr('src', 'cryptographp.inc.php');

            });

         });

         $("*").click(function() {
             $('center').fadeOut(1000, function() {
                });
        });

</script>
```

Is there anything special about input boxes that would change or cancel out an on click event? What steps can I take to debug this problem?

Comment: Your code is probably running before the element is queryable using JavaScript. Are you using a document ready handler?

Comment: I'm curious that what is `$('center')`?

Comment: @MattBall yes. see all the complete CSS above.

Answer (score 0):

Look this [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/olOrOsA/1/edit) it works perfect and i change nothing about your code...

```
$("#answerBox").click(function() {

        $('center').fadeOut(1000, function() {
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lebolo/xxVyH/) works for me.

I changed your div `id` from `left` to `center`. I also added a `#` to the jQuery selection within the click code. This assumes you were trying to select an element with ID "center". If you were trying to select a `<center>` element then leave your code as is (I didn't see a center element in the HTML).

Also, you may want to look into [.focus()](http://api.jquery.com/focus/) so that the same effect happens if the user tabs into the input box.